# bipartite graph, no odd cycles, one question about the proof

Tags: graph-theory

I found a proof of the fact that if a graph G is bipartite(1), then it cannot have any odd cycles(2). I have a question about $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$. Why is it sufficient to assume that  G is connected?

Comment: Because if $G$ isn’t connected, you can work in each component separately.

Comment: Right, indeed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: I've got one more question. When can we multiply graphs? And what does such a product graph look like?

Comment: There are [several different graph products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product); is one of these what you had in mind?

Comment: I meant a product of, for example, P which is a path $(x, v)$ and Q is a path $(y, v)$ and then $C=PQ^{-1}x$ is a cycle. My problem is that I see it is a cycle but I have no idea how to multiply graphs whose product isn't as simple as a cycle or a path.

Comment: I’m no graph theorist, but I wouldn’t have called that a product: you’re just concatenating two paths in a single graph.

Comment: Is the notation for concatenation is usually the same as above? And when talking about multiplication there is always a symbol between the graphs, isn't there?

Comment: Yes, concatenation is very often denoted by simple juxtaposition, as in $PQ^{-1}$, and yes, on the rare occasions when I’ve dealt with graph products, they’ve been explicitly indicated by some symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It's a consequence of the following:

> A graph is bipartite if and only if each of its components are bipartite.

So, for example, this graph is bipartite, since each of its components are bipartite:

[image: A multi-component bipartite graph]

This generalises to:

> A graph is $k$-colourable if and only if each of its components are $k$-colourable.

This generalises to:

> The [chromatic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) of a graph is the product of the chromatic polynomials of its components.

This generalises to:

> The [Tutte polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) of a graph is the product of the Tutte polynomials of its components.